# Creating a continuous probability distribution with parameters

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I am trying to create a continuous probability distribution and then trying to draw a random sample of size 5. Need help in creating one.

```
myK[alpha0_,beta0_,c_,w] := 
  (beta0/alpha0((c+w)/alpha0)Exp[-((c+w)/alpha0)^beta0])/Exp[-(c/alpha0)^beta0];
dist[alpha1_,beta1_c1_] = ProbabilityDistribution[myK[alpha1,beta1,c1,x],{x,0,∞}];
myK[1,1,2,w]
E^-w (2+w)
dist[1,1,2]
(* E^-w (2+w) *)

ProbabilityDistribution[myK[alpha1,beta1,c1,\[FormalX]],{\[FormalX],0,∞}][1,1,2]
RandomVariate[dist[1,1,2],5]
(* ProbabilityDistribution[myK[alpha1,beta1,c1,\[FormalX]],{\[FormalX],0,∞}][1,1,2] *)
(* RandomVariate[ProbabilityDistribution[myK[alpha1,beta1,c1,\[FormalX]],{\[FormalX],0,∞}][1,1,2],5] *)
```

Comment: Your definition of `myK` uses `w` instead of `w_`. Your definition of `dist` has strange arguments. Finally, `RandomVariate` can only produce real numbers as output, so your parameters need to be numbers when it is called.

Comment: As pointed out by Carl Woll you have a number of syntax errors. Correcting and normalizing: `myK[alpha0_, beta0_, c_, 
   w_] := (beta0/
      alpha0 ((c + w)/alpha0) Exp[-((c + w)/alpha0)^beta0])/
   Exp[-(c/alpha0)^beta0];
dist[alpha1_, beta1_, c1_] := 
  ProbabilityDistribution[
   myK[alpha1, beta1, c1, x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}
   , Method -> "Normalize"];
Plot[PDF[dist[1, 1, 2], x] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 10}]
Plot[CDF[dist[1, 1, 2], x] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
RandomVariate[dist[1, 1, 2], 5]
` should work

Comment: Thanks ubpdqn . As you can see I am trying to define a conditional distribution of Weibull with condition (x>c).

Comment: I hit the post button mistakenly. ... I am still not able to use my defined function as a distribution . And the RandomVariate is not working. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Thanks all, I also looked at the answers to the other questions posted and realized that i neded to to add  Assumptions -> , varying the ranges of the parameters.